# Load XElement from string without namespaces

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xelement

I want to load an XElement from XML string that contains prefixes of namespaces. For example:

```
string template = @"<com:PersonName>
  <com:FirstName>def</com:FirstName>
      <com:LastName>abc</com:LastName>
  </com:PersonName>";
```

In above XML com refers to a namespace like `xmlns:com = "somevalue"`
When I used `XElement.Parse(xml)` method it throws an error.

I have also tried to load such XML in XmlDocument and it allows me to achieve this using xmlreader and set namespaces to off but I want to do it using XDocuemnt or XElement.

Is it possible to load this string in Xelement without providing namespace ?

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately you have to provide a namespace for the prefix, otherwise you won't be able to parse it into an `XElement`.  One way you can work around this is to add to the string a dummy root element with a namespace definition and parse it.  Then get the child element from the parsed node.

```
var template = @"<com:PersonName>
<com:FirstName>def</com:FirstName>
    <com:LastName>abc</com:LastName>
</com:PersonName>";
var fixedTemplate = $"<root xmlns:com=\"somevalue\">{template}</root>";
var element = XElement.Parse(fixedTemplate).Elements().Single();
```